# What are the rules for salutations on Meta?

Tags: discussion, edits, meta, signatures

<strike>Welcome back my friends to the show that never ends!</strike>

I know that salutations and variations on the phrase "thanks" are *strongly discouraged* on SO, but a quick search doesn't show a clear statement for Meta (although the FAQ is clear on signatures).  Are they to be discouraged and edited away on sight here, just like they are on the main site?

Comment: Why would it be different?

Comment: Edit anything that isn't either `Wassuuuuuuuup!!!` or `'sup, dawg?`.

Comment: @random - some things, like voting, do work a bit differently here. I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @shanethehat: While the rules are the same, be careful about going on an editing spree when you don't have full editing privileges. You should *definitely* remove greetings/salutations/whatever while you're editing and making other improvements, but people approving your edits might get annoyed and start clicking "Reject" instead if that's the *only* thing you're doing. (Once you hit 2k though, you're off to the races.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

<strike>Deeer fr8end,</strike>

Salutations on meta are just as welcome as salutations on Stack Overflow. They get in the way of content and are filtered out. Nothing personal, just don't do it.

<strike>Thanks,

The management</strike>

Comment: Marvellous. I'd seen a few recently, but wanted to check before starting editing.

Comment: This should be added to the FAQ, I was about to post a question about this, since my questions were getting edited out for the "have a nice day" part at the end of them.

Answer (score 10):

Comment: This is just to demonstrate that many (most?) common salutations are actually deleted automagically. So no, they aren't allowed here either. The post consisted of "Hello!" and some stuff to meet the minimum quantity of characters.

Comment: LEAVE US KIDS ALONE!