# Are there ever going to be more badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

Are there ever going to be more badges added, and possible to get?

Comment: right now you're naked. You need to put on a badge.

Comment: I hope they add more badges that are impossible to get, too.

Comment: @SilverHorn Please do not rollback the post, there is no need for your signature in the body. Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your [user](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/167612/silverhorn) page.

Comment: For talking to someone with such a high rank in authority, you get the horns!

Comment: @Horns, what do you mean by `possible to get`? As far as I can tell, all the badges except *beta* are possible to get.

Comment: 0 users have gotten "precognitive".

Comment: Silly them. I would have, but I already knew I couldn't.

Comment: How do you get it?

Comment: [Don't do that, it's not in "Da Rules"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Regarding Precognitive, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71712/should-the-precognitive-badge-be-listed-in-the-list-of-sofu-badges).

Comment: Bobby's quite right, [your rollbacks are not appreciated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102509/what-are-the-rules-for-salutations-on-meta). In particual the `–SilverHorn` in the last line is 100% superfluous as your user name already appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: I know that. I'm just being professional. P.S. Please don't call me "Horns".

Comment: Being petty and disregarding the norms is anything but professional

Answer (score 13):

Probably. They added two new ones just this week.

EDIT:
I suppose if I'm going to post an answer at all, I should explain more. The team can add badges at will. They often add badges when new major features are introduced, to get people to use them or at least be aware of them.

Other times, new badges' criteria are suggested by or at least inspired by the community. You can suggest your own badges here on MSO by posting new questions explaining your desired criteria with the tag [badge-request](/questions/tagged/badge-request). Looking through old questions with that tag is a good way to see what does/doesn't make a good request.

You can see a partial history of new badges being added at the [list of recent SE feature changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange).

Answer (score 6):

Right in the recent past new badges have been added: [Excavator](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1287/excavator) has been added about one day ago, and [Proofreader](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1276/proofreader) was recently added.
If by "possible to get" you mean possible to get for users with a reputation of, e.g., 500, then I think there is few that is not already covered by existing badges.

Consider also that a badge is created to promote a positive behavior on an SE site; they are not added for the sake of adding them. For example, you could think of adding a badge for who commented 200 times, but as this is not the behavior an SE site wants to promote, such badge will not be added.

Comment: Well, there is the [Pundit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/40/pundit) badge, which is for *upvoted* commenting...

Comment: @Benjol Right, but that has a different target, and it is for only 10 comments; it is not about writing 200 comments to get a badge simply for the fact you wrote them.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Comment: The [newest one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/158/excavator) was added yesterday, so chances are indeed good.

Comment: @balpha And I excavated one of them!